# how to use variables in os.rename

Tags: python, file-rename

I have a file `name.txt` and want to rename it with pyhton.

```
my_path = "/home/user/folder1/folder2/name.txt
new_name= "name2.txt"

os.rename(my_path, new_name)
```

When I execute this program it works however the new file lives in the same folder as  the python program. Is there any way to get the new file into the directory of `my_path` with variables instead of hardcoding it?

I tried `new_name = my_path - "name.txt"` but it didn't work

**EDIT** got it to work thanks to the answer below:

```
my_path = "/home/user/folder1/folder2/name.txt"
new_name ="name2.txt"
new_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(my_path), new_name)
os.rename(my_path, new_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> os.path.join(os.path.dirname("/home/user/folder1/folder2/name.txt"), "name2.txt")
'/home/user/folder1/folder2/name2.txt'
```